# Python Leap motion Libraries not working

Tags: python-3.x, leap-motion

I am trying to use my Leap motion in Python 3.4, but I cant even get `import Leap` to work. The python file I am trying to run is on my desktop, along with all the library files (Leap.py, LeapPython.pyd, Leap.dll, and Leap.lib). Whenever I try to run `import Leap` in my code, the program just throws this:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm not sure what DLL its talking about, I already tried putting msvcp120.dll and msvcr120.dll in the same directory.

I am using Leap Motion SDK Version V2.3.1.31549 on a 64 bit Windows 10 with the 32 bit version of Python 3.4

All help is appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Leap Motion SDK only supports Python 2.7.

Some people have reported success using SWIG to regenerate the Python wrapper for Python 3 (the SWIG .i file is included in the SDK). You could also use the LeapC library to to create a Ctypes-based wrapper, which could support multiple versions of Python.

Comment: I did not know that the library was only for Python 2.7. I just installed 2.7 and imported the library and it worked fine! Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: @charles - I tried the same thing. Followed this tutorial provided by  leap motion https://support.leapmotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/223784048
I could'nt get it to work. So, I should be using LeapC.h library instead of just Leap.h ?